# Solving parametric ODEs

Tags: differential-equations, parametric-functions

Consider the equation $dx/dt = f(x, m)$, where $x$ is a function of $t$, x and $m$ is a parameter.

In Mathematica notation, `f[x, m]` is a function of `x[t]` and some parameter `m`.

Solutions of $dx/dt = f(x, m)$ vary with $t$ with the initial value $x(0)=x0$, and with the parameter $m$. When a certain $f(x, m)$ is given, how can I make a notebook that produces graphs of the solution sets of  $dx/dt = f(x, m)$ along with controls to manipulate the values of $x0$ and $m$?

Examples: $f1(x) = x(m - x),\, f2(x) = 1 + m - x^2$

I can't really conceptualize solving this type of differential equation with Mathematica, where $x$ is a function of an independent variable. I have learned to solve ODE's with `DSolve`, but how does this function work if the variable is also a function of another variable?

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just use [`DSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolveValue) in the usual way (an example using your `f1` function):

```
With[{expr = DSolveValue[{x'[t]==x[t](m-x[t]), x[0]==x0}, x[t], t]},
    Manipulate[Plot[expr, {t,0,1}], {{x0,1},0,10}, {{m,2},0,10}]
]
```

> Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.

[image]